# Querying from routine in jOOQ

Tags: sql, postgresql, jooq

I have a PostgreSQL function that returns a set of UDTs (i.e. its function signature includes `RETURNS SETOF <UDT name>`). I'm trying to run the following query in jOOQ:

```
SELECT col1, col2
FROM custom_function(param1, param2)
```

jOOQ codegen has generated the routine for `custom_function`. However, I can't use that routine in the `from()` clause because the routine returns a `Field` whereas `from()` expects a `Table`.

What's the best way to run the above query in jOOQ? I know I can just write the query in plain SQL, but I'd like to see if there's a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicit support for PostgreSQL functions returning `SETOF` types is not yet implemented, but it's on the roadmap:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3376

The upcoming jOOQ 3.5.0 will support table-valued functions, though, i.e. tables that return `TABLE` types:

- https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/3375

Until these features are supported, your best bet is to [resort to plain SQL](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql/), e.g.:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(DSL.field("col1"), DSL.field("col2"))
   .from("custom_function(param1, param2)")
   .fetch();
```